# Windows 10 adds border to window when starting at a higher DPI and changing to a lower DPI

Tags: winapi, highdpi

I have a window with styles `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST` and `WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`. This window is configured as PerMonitor DPI supported.  The client area is filled with a gradient as the background.  There are buttons on there as well.

If I change the DPI higher, everything looks good with the window.  However, if I start at a higher DPI and change to a lower DPI, it adds a mystery border around the client area, although when the button is redrawn, it can cover that area.  Also, when it does the border, it will flash until clicked on, then I can click out.  When clicked on and active, it's darkened.  When clicking outside the window, it's white (almost like some miscalculation for the shadow?).

I'm using Win10 build 1909.

Anyway, a picture is worth a thousand words:

Normal:

[image]

After scaling from (starting) higher to lower DPI:

[image]

Comment: Changing the DPI breaks a lot of things until after a reboot. OS limitation.

Comment: is your app declared as permonitoraware2?

Comment: yes as well as permonitor

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: After many attempts, I can only capture the gray border. Note: The window is inactive. See this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Tml.png).

Comment: Use the same styles so you can compare. Make it all version (compatible with all windows supporting DPI changes for the manifest).  Draw the client area with your own background on erase.   set DPI to 200%, start up the app, then scale to something less than 200%.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the problem. My system is 1903. Have you tested it on other computer versions? For example, 1903. When the dpi changes from 175% to less than 175%, will the problem arise? Because I found that [my computer only supports 175% at most](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhY6p.png).